# want to fetch multiple records of same user using join in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, join

I have 4 tables of applicant i.e applicantEducation, applicantProfessionalInfo, applicantProjects, applicantCertificates. I want to make e function in which when i pass id of applicant that on the bases of that applicantId i want to fetch data of that applicant from these 4 tables. I have 3 pojects of same applicant. Now when i query the database then it is returning full data set from all 4 tables 3 times because in applicantProfessionalInfo table there are 3 jobs records for same applicant .And in rest of the 3 tables of applicant there is one record across this user. Here is my join query

https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5a2c8d159b451a3mjb0384tl

I am recieving data in this format from api response

```
{
"meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success"
},
"data": [
    {
        "FirstName": "Saad",
        "LastName": "Subzwari",
        "FatherName": "Naeem Uz Zafar Subzwari",
        "Contact": "923485255",
        "Address": "b17/519",
        "Cnic": "42501-6143456-9",
        "ProfilePicture": "",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "DOB": "1992-05-07",
        "DegreeName": "BBA",
        "Major": "Accounting",
        "Institute": "Computer Colligiate",
        "CompletionDate": "2013-12-31T19:00:00.000Z",
        "Gpa": 2.9,
        "duration": "12 Months",
        "organization": "10 Pearls",
        "Position": "SQA",
        "CertificateName": ".Net Diploma",
        "Url": "www.afreekmoji.com",
        "Year": 2015,
        "ProjectTitle": "AfrikMoji",
        "Skills": "Bootstrap, Javascript",
        "ProjectDesc": "Emoji selling website"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Saad",
        "LastName": "Subzwari",
        "FatherName": "Naeem Uz Zafar Subzwari",
        "Contact": "923485255",
        "Address": "b17/519",
        "Cnic": "42501-6143456-9",
        "ProfilePicture": "",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "DOB": "1992-05-07",
        "DegreeName": "BBA",
        "Major": "Accounting",
        "Institute": "Computer Colligiate",
        "CompletionDate": "2013-12-31T19:00:00.000Z",
        "Gpa": 2.9,
        "duration": "5 Months ",
        "organization": "Axact",
        "Position": "Senior .Net Developer",
        "CertificateName": ".Net Diploma",
        "Url": "www.afreekmoji.com",
        "Year": 2015,
        "ProjectTitle": "AfrikMoji",
        "Skills": "Bootstrap, Javascript",
        "ProjectDesc": "Emoji selling website"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Saad",
        "LastName": "Subzwari",
        "FatherName": "Naeem Uz Zafar Subzwari",
        "Contact": "923485255",
        "Address": "b17/519",
        "Cnic": "42501-6143456-9",
        "ProfilePicture": "",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "DOB": "1992-05-07",
        "DegreeName": "BBA",
        "Major": "Accounting",
        "Institute": "Computer Colligiate",
        "CompletionDate": "2013-12-31T19:00:00.000Z",
        "Gpa": 2.9,
        "duration": "8 Months",
        "organization": "Tech Consultancy ",
        "Position": ".Net Developer",
        "CertificateName": ".Net Diploma",
        "Url": "www.afreekmoji.com",
        "Year": 2015,
        "ProjectTitle": "AfrikMoji",
        "Skills": "Bootstrap, Javascript",
        "ProjectDesc": "Emoji selling website"
    }
   ]
   }
```

In this data , data is repeating 3 times because applicant have 3 job records in applicantProfessionalInfo table. But i want to have data like this

```
"data": [
    {
        "FirstName": "Saad",
        "LastName": "Subzwari",
        "FatherName": "Naeem Uz Zafar Subzwari",
        "Contact": "923485255",
        "Address": "b17/519",
        "Cnic": "42501-6143456-9",
        "ProfilePicture": "",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "DOB": "1992-05-07",
        "DegreeName": "BBA",
        "Major": "Accounting",
        "Institute": "Computer Colligiate",
        "CompletionDate": "2013-12-31T19:00:00.000Z",
        "Gpa": 2.9,
        "duration": "12 Months",
        "organization": "10 Pearls",
        "Position": "SQA",
        "duration": "5 Months ",
        "organization": "Axact",
        "Position": "Senior .Net Developer",
        "duration": "8 Months",
        "organization": "Tech Consultancy ",
        "Position": ".Net Developer"
    }
```

how can i achieve this result?

Comment: You cannot achieve this results through sql query alone, since you cannot have exactly the same field names multiple times in an SQL resultset. Also, the sample code is for sqlite, while the question is tagged as mysql. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Shadow so how can i achieve this result? can you guide me? and i am using mysql